# django integrityerror appending _id to the end of my attribute name

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, integrity

i have read a few of the examples regarding integrirty errors caused by appending _id to the end of an attribute but most of them regard user_id which is not the error i have - mine is dealing with a setting the initial value of a foreign key to another model (recipe has fk to cookbook)

so here is my trace

```
IntegrityError at /cookbook/createrecipe/

(1048, "Column 'original_cookbook_id' cannot be null")

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cookbook/createrecipe/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

(1048, "Column 'original_cookbook_id' cannot be null")

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.1
def createrecipe(request):

        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)

        if request.method == 'POST':

            if form.is_valid():

                form = RecipeForm(initial = {'original_cookbook' : request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]})

                recipe = form.save()//error

...

            t = loader.get_template('cookbook/create_form.html')

            c = RequestContext(request, {

                'form': form,

            })

            data = {

            'form': t.render(c),
```

as you can probably see i have a foreign_key named original_cookbook that i want to set initial to the cookbook of the user.

any idea what might be causing this i can send more code if needed

thanks

snackerfish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.....

```
form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
  if form.is_valid():
    recipe = form.save(commit=False)
    recipe.original_cookbook = request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]
    recipe.save()
```

Comment: this seems to have worked although i believe i have other errors occuring thank you